# plus minus signs do not synchronize with my accordion menu

Tags: jquery

the first plus minus sign works...on page load, the ul is unhidden, and the icon is a minus sign. the others are correct as well and are plus signs, but those uls are hidden (hence looking like open and closed accordion menus).

Why do I have to click the others twice? This destroys the plus minus syncing.

JS fiddle link could help but I don't know: http://jsfiddle.net/Ft6tg/

```
  HTML with a ul with sub uls exists in this system... this is implied.
```

JS

```
//navigation.js file 
//opens the accordion on page load
//I made it so that the menu where that link is, is open on page load

//a function

// title for open accordion ul now gets a minus sign put beside it (this is an h2 within an li)
    $(subSectionLi).find('#toggle-icon').html(("<i class='fa fa-minus-circle'></i>"));  

//end of function

//dropdown.js file
//does the toggles on that page, and selects the font awesome circle-plus minus

$("#aside").on('click','div span h2',function(event){
    var el = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('#dropdown');
    if ( !el.is(':animated') ) {

    $(el).slideToggle('slow');
     event.preventDefault();
     var accordion =  $(this).children('span#toggle-icon');

     var menu = $("#dropdown.dropMenu");
     accordion.toggleClass("closed");


        if ($(accordion).hasClass("closed")){ 
            // change plus/minus icon
            accordion.html("<i class='fa fa-plus-circle'></i>");
            } else {
            accordion.html("<i class='fa fa-minus-circle'></i>");
        }
   }
});
```

Comment: Your fiddle has a bunch of errors, and doesn't really work at all. Open the console.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pluses/minuses not syncing for accordion menu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25062416/pluses-minuses-not-syncing-for-accordion-menu)

Comment: If you asked a question, and don't receive immidiate feedback, there is no need to start another question with the same content! Instead try editing your original question. You should not start the same question if you haven't had an answer in 1 day.

Comment: I did but it seemed as though people abandonned it after that. nevermind...I found a person here who knows what he is doing. Cheers!